# List of Non Tower Airport - World?

Tags: air-traffic-control

May I know the Non-Tower Airports throughout the World - List. Please ?

Comment: I seriously doubt such a thing even exists.

Comment: There are literally _thousands_ of them.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a list of all non-towered airports in the world, do following:

1. Visit the [data section](http://ourairports.com/data/) of ourairports.com
2. Download the files `airports.csv` and `airport-frequencies.cvs`
3. Read through every airport in the first file and search for the respective frequencies in the second file
4. If there is no tower frequency for the airport you are iterating through, write the ICAO-Code into another file
5. When finished, you have a list of all non-towered airports

If you have programming experience you should be able to do this.

Comment: This is a good piece of teaching somebody to fish.